# ERROR in register.php

Tags: php, function, registration

Please help:
 Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\ooploginreg\functions.php on line 14 Call Stack # Time Memory Function Location 1 0.0010 252552 {main}( ) ..\register.php:0 2 0.0020 265888 LoginRegistration->registerUser( ) ..\register.php:50

Codeline in functions.php:

```
<?php
require "config.php";

class LoginRegistration{

function _construct(){
    $database = new DatabaseConnection();
}

public function registerUser($username, $password, $name, $email, $website){
    global $pdo;

    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ? AND email = ?");
    $query->execute(array($username, $email));
    $num = $query->rowCount;

    if($num == 0){
        $query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password, name, email, website)VALUES (?, ?, ?, ? ,?)");
        $query->execute(array($username, $password, $name, $email, $website));
        return true;
    }else{
        return print "<span style='color:=#e53d37'>Error...username/email already used.</span>";
    }
}
}

?>
```

Comment: check connection method/API and variables.

Comment: yo `_construct` <<<<<<<<<<<< like I said above there, your connection's failing. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php it's **typo**

Comment: Which prepare statement is line 12?

Comment: here is:    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ? AND email = ?");

Comment: `_construct` missing underscore. so.... `__construct` which is a reason why your code is failing.

Comment: Even if that constructor did run, the code assigns it to a local variable `$database` (thrown away afterwards). While your query code depends on a global `$pdo`. Decide on one approach first.

Comment: config.php                                                                                             <?php
class DatabaseConnection{
 public function _construct(){
  global $pdo;
  try{
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=oopreg', 'root', '');
        } catch (PDOException $e){
   exit('Database error');
  }
 }
}
?>

Comment: I think you missing opening of the database connection

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling  $pdo before it is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You called database connection in constructor. But your var "pdo" already have value. Your PDO make some data before this class runs.

Just Use

```
$this->database = new DatabaseConnection();
```

Comment: Thank you, I did it but there is no change, see here:                                                  Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\ooploginreg\functions.php on line 14                                                                                        Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0010 252552 {main}( ) ..\register.php:0
2 0.0020 265888 LoginRegistration->registerUser( ) ..\register.php:50

Comment: You shoud replace all PDO var on "$this->database" call. And after this if you have some troubles list here new code.

Answer (score 0):

You create the variable `$database` but never used it:

```
$database = new DatabaseConnection();
```

---

**Problems**

- You never used the $database variable
- It is bad practice to use global
- It is bad practice to have your class depend on database object
- Connection should be passed to constructor

**Solution**

Your class should be like this:

```
class LoginRegistration
{
    private $pdo;
    function __construct($database)
    {
        $this->pdo = $database;
    }

    public function registerUser($username, $password, $name, $email, $website)
    {
        $query = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ? AND email = ?");
        $query->execute(array($username, $email));
        $num = $query->rowCount;

        if ($num == 0) {
            $query = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password, name, email, website)VALUES (?, ?, ?, ? ,?)");
            $query->execute(array($username, $password, $name, $email, $website));
            return true;
        } else {
            return print "<span style='color:=#e53d37'>Error...username/email already used.</span>";
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
$database = new DatabaseConnection();
$login = new LoginRegistration($database);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot meda, I did it but there is error:Warning: Missing argument 1 for LoginRegistration::__construct(), called in C:\wamp\www\ooploginreg\register.php on line 3 and defined in C:\wamp\www\ooploginreg\functions.php on line 7
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0020 247792 {main}( ) ..\register.php:0
2 0.0040 267016 LoginRegistration->__construct( )                                                                                                                   Notice: Undefined variable: database in C:\wamp\www\ooploginreg\functions.php on line 9

Comment: Dude i gave you the full answer, this error is complaining that you are not passing the parameter to the constructor

Comment: Thank you all, my fault I have not hiked two lines on the constructor.